# ruby - text parse issues when populating from database

Tags: ruby

tried to create simple dropdown in ruby with values from the database - like that :

```
<% ingredientArray = Ingredient.all.map { |ingredient| [ingredient.name, ingredient.id] } %>
<div class="field">
  <%= select_tag(:ingredient_id, ingredientArray) %><br/>
</div>
```

and I received an empy one.
this is the generated html

```
<div class="field">
   <select id="ingredient_id" name="ingredient_id">[[&quot;Paprika&quot;, 5], [&quot;Cinnamon&quot;, 8], [&quot;Salt&quot;, 9], [&quot;Pepper&quot;, 10], [&quot;water&quot;, 11]]</select><br/>
</div>
```

where should I put html sage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read documentation on [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) and related methods.
The second parameter of it is a string containing the option tags for the select box. 
You can generate in manually:

```
select_tag "people", "<option>David</option>".html_safe
```

Or use **options_from_collection_for_select** method for it:

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name")
```

(Examples from the docs)

Specifically in your case the best way to make that dropdown is:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= select_tag("Ingredients", options_from_collection_for_select(Ingredient.all, 'id', 'name')) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) like so:

```
<%= collection_select :recipe, :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "&ndash; Select an Ingredient &ndash;".html_safe } %>
```

(I've assumed the parent object you are trying to assign the ingredient ids to is `:recipe`. Change that value as it fits your app.)